# Possible to Drive Object Properties with Motion Tween?

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, parallax, tween

I'm trying to create a complex parallax effect in Flash video sequence that includes translation and scaling among many layers.

I've been looking for a way to set up my scene to where I could just animate one object (preferably with motion tween) and then apply some percentage of that animation to each background object (or flip values accordingly).

Is there any way to harvest Motion Tween data out of a layer of a MovieClip and translate that into x,y values for objects? [So far I've only created instances of objects and set their positions through actionscript.]

Comment: Does motion tween not just change x and y coordinates? Why can't you just read the x/y coordinates of whatever object you want to base the others off of?

Comment: @NealDavis because the properties of objects might get rounded. (x and y for example are rounded to 1/20th pixel steps) other properties might not get round and could very well have intermediate values. It's better to base calculations on some higher resolution tweening value (likely a floating point value going from 0 to 1) to base calculations on.

Comment: @NealDavis I'm not sure how to get that X/Y information from the object that I've animated in Flash. The closest thing I've found is the "Copy Motion as Action Script..." command. That spits out a bunch of arrays that I could use to influence other layers/objects, but I'd have to be constantly updating those arrays any time I make a tweak to the animation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to use a [copy motion](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/learning_guide/animation/part06.html#copying) option of the layer context menu
Also tweening actionscript libraries e.g. [TweenMax](https://greensock.com/tweenmax) are capable of tweening any properties of any objects, but they do it with actionscript (which can be easily copied/modified/pasted), not Adobe Flash UI.

Comment: Copy Motion does a straight copy of curve values from one layer to another, but in order to create a parallax effect, I actually want other layers to inherit only a percentage of the animation, or possibly move in the other direction. As far as I know, there's no way to adjust the values of an entire curve, which means I'd be left adjusting 1000s of keyframes manually. The other trouble being if I want to iterate on the animation, I'd have to copy and adjust everything again.

Comment: I did notice there's a "Copy Motion as Action Script..." command. That spits out a giant array of keyframe data.

I could conceivably copy/paste that array and apply it differently to each layer.

Answer (score 1):

So converting every visual element to a movieclip allowed me to position the items in Z as well. That pretty much solved my problem.

Thanks everyone.